# Mac exectuable only starts with ./name even when $path set

Tags: mac, path

I'm trying to install Mongo but having trouble with the $PATH var in MacOS. Following the guidelines. My $PATH is set in .bash_profile:

```
 export PATH=/Users/evl/dev/mongodb/bin⁩:$PATH
```

which works:

```
echo $PATH
/Users/evl/dev/mongodb/bin⁩:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

entering mongo on command line from other directory:

```
:~ evl$ mongo
-bash: mongo: command not found
```

I expected that mongo would be found now the $PATH is set

entering ./mongo on command line from mongo bin directory:

```
cd /Users/evl/dev/mongodb/bin⁩
./mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
```

So now mongo runs. But only if I move to the folder and I enter './mongo'.

I would expect with the $PATH variable set correctly, the executable would run from any directory. It should actually. What is going wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you restarted Terminal or tried in a new shell? I assume you aded the export $PATH to ~./bash_profile or ~/.bashrc

Comment: @Mark If `echo $PATH` shows the new path the environment seems to be correct.

Comment: What is the output of running `type -a mongo`.

Comment: @nohillside not if just entered in current session. bash caches the items on the PATH so needs rehash or a  new shell

Comment: $ type -a mongo
-bash: type: mongo: not found

Comment: $ type -a ./mongo
./mongo is ./mongo

Comment: even after restarting computer .. still the same

Comment: interestingly enough, when I simply try 'cat mongo' the executable appears! So he can find the file. He simply refuses to run it. Something must be wrong in the path var..

Answer (score 1):

I just typed everything again, exactly the same as before, but no copy-paste, and now the issue was gone. Some strange characters, invisible, might have shifted in .. Weird.. but happy to continue now..